# SWT GC Draw and Rotate Text Around Circle

Tags: java, swt

I've found this compass written in JavaFx.
https://harmoniccode.blogspot.com/2014/04/just-because-you-asked-for-it.html

I'm trying to draw it using SWT GC, but I'm not able to draw and rotate the texts (N, 3, 6, E, 12, etc.) around the circle.

[image]

Does anyone know how to do that using SWT GC?

Comment: Look at `GC.setTransform`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw rotated text inside of a GC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618023/how-to-draw-rotated-text-inside-of-a-gc)